# Reversing the flow of JQuery-Terminal

Tags: jquery-terminal

Is it possible to have new command results push previous command results down? This is kind of opposite from how JQuery works out of the box with new commands being entered below the entire command history of the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately there is in CSS new addition which is flexbox, you can reorder elements on the page with it:

```
.terminal-output {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

this will make command line at the bottom and commands be in reverse order. If you additionally want to have command line at the top use this:

```
.terminal-wrapper, .terminal-output {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

You also will need to have option `{scroll: false}` to disable scrolling to bottom on echo. If it will scroll in other actions and if this is annoying you can report a bug with this.